# How do you relate/link two elements together with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like so:

```
<table>
<tr id="green-row" class="green"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="red-row" class="red"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="blue-row" class="blue"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

And then I have buttons on the same page (but separate from the table) like so:

```
<button id="add-green" class="green">Add Green Product</button>
<button id="add-red" class="red">Add Red Product</button>
<button id="add-blue" class="blue">Add Blue Product</button>
```

Is there a way to have the actions on each button correspond to its associated table row, without have to use the specific ID each time?

For example, I know I can do something like this:

```
$('#add-green').click(function() {
   $('#green-row td').append('<p>Added Green Product</p>')
});
```

But rather than have to write that three times for each product, is there a simpler way to just "link" the table row and the button together with the same class or a rel or something? (I'm new to jquery as you can see.)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mqp5ev2p/3/

Comment: Hint: if you want an action to work on multiple similar elements, most of the times classes are going to be best over id's.

Comment: Thanks blex. I added the same class to each row and button, so now I just need to figure out how to say "When you click on button, do this to the table row that has the same class" without having to use the specific class name in the function. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just updated your Fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/mqp5ev2p/7/):

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var col = $(this).attr("class");
  var colcopy = $(this).text();
  $("td." + col).append(colcopy);
});
```

And added classes red, blue and green for the buttons and the td. Think you can  adjust it further.

Comment: Yes I know, therefore the last sentence as I just thought OP can figure out to handle the rest on her own. Just giving hints for the question and not always providing the full solution here ;)

Comment: This worked great. Now I realize how simple it was. This has definitely helped me understand it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This my help you

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr data-relation="green"><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-relation="red"><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-relation="blue"><td></td></tr>
</table>

<button class="mybtn" data-relation="green">Add Green Product</button>
<button class="mybtn" data-relation="red">Add Red Product</button>
<button class="mybtn" data-relation="blue">Add Blue Product</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mybtn").click(function(){
        var selected = $(this).attr("data-relation");
        var valuetoappend = $(this).html();
        $("#mytable tr").each(function(){
            var relation = $(this).attr("data-relation");
            if(selected===relation)
                $(this).next().append(valuetoappend);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your specific case

```
$('button[id^="add"]').click(function(){
    var idPart = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    $('tr[id^="'+idPart+'"] td').append('<p>Added '+ idPart+' Product</p>');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqp5ev2p/5/)

It will add as `Added red Product` If you want to get color name starts with capital letter. Use this line

```
$('tr[id^="'+idPart+'"] td').append('<p>Added '+ idPart.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + idPart.slice(1) +' Product</p>');
```